# JQuery Slide Toggle Close and Open Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all , please bear with me about my bad english :(

I am listing data in a table using for-each loop and above HTML will generate if use to slideToggle then it open fine.
but if another row open then last one still open , i want to open a new one but close previous.

```
function view_history_details  (  ) {

    $('#view-details').slideToggle();
}

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:;"  onclick="view_history_details()" title="View" data-keyboard="false" ></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    some text
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:;"  onclick="view_history_details()" title="View" data-keyboard="false" ></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    some text
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:;"  onclick="view_history_details()" title="View" data-keyboard="false" ></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    some text
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redesign the solution as below using jQuery event handlers.

We adds a class to the `anchor` elements which triggers the action, then use that class to register the click handlers. Inside the handler we toggles the next `view-details` row and hides all other `view-details` elements

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    console.log(this)
    e.preventDefault();
    var $cur = $(this).closest('tr').next('.view-details').stop().toggle();
    $('.view-details').not($cur).stop().hide();
  })
})
```

```css
.toggle {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="toggle" title="View" data-keyboard="false">togggle</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="toggle" title="View" data-keyboard="false">togggle</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="toggle" title="View" data-keyboard="false">togggle</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass particular control to your function so as to `slideToggle` only that control's `view-details` element as below:

```
function view_history_details  (ctrl) {
    $('.view-details').slideUp();
    $(ctrl).closest('tr').next('.view-details').slideToggle();
}
```

and when calling function from `td` write it as below and pass `this`

```
<td>
     <a href="javascript:;"  onclick="view_history_details(this)" title="View" data-keyboard="false" ></a>
</td>
```

Repeat for all `td`s where `view_history_details` function call exists.

**DEMO**

```js
function view_history_details  (ctrl) {
    $('.view-details').slideUp('fast');
    $(ctrl).closest('tr').next('.view-details').slideToggle('slow');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="view_history_details(this)" title="View" data-keyboard="false">View Details</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="view_history_details(this)" title="View" data-keyboard="false">View Details</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="view_history_details(this)" title="View" data-keyboard="false">View Details</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none" class="view-details">
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```